# Delphi XE7 Android IOS VPN

Tags: android, ios, delphi, vpn, delphi-xe7

I'm using Embarcadero Delphi XE7 UP1, i was wondering is there any chance to findout mobile device is connected to vpn ? If not connected is there any way to trigger mobile device's default vpn client or directly connect to vpn on Androis & IOS ?